# Grab original index in Google Visualization Table after sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, google-visualization, selection

I made a multiselect on the Google Table where it allows the user to just select and unselect with just clicking instead of pressing on the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to select multiple. I used this to get the original index:

```
tdIndex = $(this).parent('tr').index();
```

But it changes index after sorting the table. Is there a way that I can save the index after sorting while the rows are still selected. After sorting, the index refreshes and when the user unselects, it unselects the last item in the new array index instead of the original array.

Comment: Did you try the getSortInfo() method?

Comment: @dlaliberte I can't seem to implement the getSortInfo() method correctly. Would it be any different from using getSortedRows()?

Comment: getSortInfo() is a method on the Table chart to "retrieve information about the current sort stateof a table that has been sorted (typically by the user, who has clicked on a column heading to sort the rows by a specific column)."  See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#methods  The getSortedRows() method is on DataTable and DataView, to get the row indices of the sorted data.  However, the Table chart keeps its own internal copy of the sorted rows, which getSortInfo() gives access to.